# Jenkins job generated by job-dsl are not picking up default Maven settings

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm running a Jenkins 2.25 server on Windows Server 2012.  At the moment we're using the Maven Integration Plugin 2.12.1 and the Job DSL Plugin 1.57.

I've written DSL scripts for around 200 existing jobs on our server.

For any jobs that use Maven, either as a build step or as an actual Maven, I'm having a really frustrating issue. When I run the generated jobs, they fail with the following output.

```
12:17:12 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.googlecode.maven-download-    plugin:download-maven-plugin:1.3.0:wget (default) on project myprojecy: The     parameters 'url' for goal com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:download-maven-plugin:1.3.0:wget are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
12:17:12 [ERROR] 
12:17:12 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
12:17:12 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
12:17:12 [ERROR] 
12:17:12 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
12:17:12 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
```

Initially we thought we identified the issue as being that we were missing the XML snippet, even thought it appeared these settings were as they should be in the UI.

```
<settings class="jenkins.mvn.DefaultSettingsProvider"/> 
<globalSettings class="jenkins.mvn.DefaultGlobalSettingsProvider"/> 
<injectBuildVariables>false</injectBuildVariables>
```

So added this to the scripts:

```
configure { node ->
node / settings (class: 'jenkins.mvn.DefaultSettingsProvider') {
}
node / globalSettings (class: 'jenkins.mvn.DefaultGlobalSettingsProvider') {
}
node / injectBuildVariables ('false') {
}
}
```

But the jobs still fail when I try to run them, even though the XML now contained this snippet as expected.

Now two very bizarre things that I can't work out which are clearly related.  Firstly, after the jobs fail, if I manually select "configure" for the job, then save it (i.e. don't make any actual changes), the job runs fine forever more (until a seed job us run and then it fails again).

Secondly, in the job config history after I run the seed job, I see the changes made when the seed job runs under the System user. However, within a matter of seconds, every time, another configuration change is recorded under my username, despite the fact that I have not made any changes to the job config - this is independent of me saving the job without making changes, by the way, it happens instantly.

I should add that further inspection suggests to me that there is some default settings for Maven which are not being applied to my DSL generated jobs. When adding the -X switch to the Maven goals, I could see more information about where these jobs are failing.  The output is:

```
 15:06:31 [DEBUG] Goal:          com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:download-maven-plugin:1.3.0:wget (default) 
 15:06:31 [DEBUG] Style:         Regular 
 15:06:31 [DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 15:06:31 <configuration> 
 15:06:31   <cacheDirectory>${download.cache.directory}</cacheDirectory> 
 15:06:31   <checkSignature default-value="false">${checkSignature}</checkSignature> 
 15:06:31   <failOnError default-value="true"/> 
 15:06:31   <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}">D:\data\jenkins\workspace\project\target</outputDirectory> 
 15:06:31   <outputFileName>${jarsigner.keystore.filename}</outputFileName> 
 15:06:31   <overwrite>${download.overwrite}</overwrite> 
 15:06:31   <readTimeOut default-value="0"/> 
 15:06:31   <retries default-value="2"/> 
 15:06:31   <session>${session}</session> 
 15:06:31   <skip default-value="false">${download.plugin.skip}</skip> 
 15:06:31   <skipCache default-value="false"/> 
 15:06:31   <unpack default-value="false">false</unpack> 
 15:06:31   <url>${jarsigner.keystore.url}</url> 
 15:06:31 </configuration>
```

Where in the successful run of the job (post fake config change) some of those fields are full, for example a URL for the keystore.  This is obviously the problem, but I don't know what to do. As far as I can tell this should be resolved by including the configure block above in the groovy, but somehow my jobs are missing this (but they have it after saving the job again with no changes).

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: For the second part of your question, see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/job-dsl-plugin/Ab9dHd1LnZU/dBO--SO2AAAJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this code in the XML which is automatically generated:

```
<jvmOptions></jvmOptions>
```

It seems that despite being empty this is overriding any default Maven options but then when the job gets saved again this is taken out because it is empty.  Resolved by adding this to the groovy script:

```
configure({
            it.remove(it / 'jvmOptions')
        })
```

This seems likely to be a bug in the DSL but it's surprising that my colleagues and I have been unable to find any mention of this. Anyway, the above resolved this for me.